# ListEmptyComponent not showing message when the FlatList is empty in React Native IOS App

Tags: react-native, expo, flatlist

I am a developing an Iphone App using React Native.I want to display folders through a FlatList.For a User, they have specific folders assigned which has images from Google Cloud Platform.
I am getting the folders for a user correctly, but when the user has no specific folders I want a message to be displayed as 'No Folders available'.I have used ListEmptyComponent to render the message.Below is the code:

DownloadPage.js:

```
import React,{useEffect,useState} from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet,SafeAreaView,TouchableOpacity,Image,FlatList,Text} from 
'react-native';
import { useSelector,useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import AsyncStorage  from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import * as authActions from "../../store/actions/auth";
import { HeaderButtons, Item } from 'react-navigation-header-buttons';
import HeaderButton from '../../components/UI/HeaderButton'; 

const DownloadPage = (props) =>{
const student = useSelector(state => state.auth.availableDevice);
const dispatch = useDispatch(); 

const renderEmptyContainer = () =>{
<View style={styles.MainContainer}>
<View style={styles.emptyTextDisplayView}>
<Text style={styles.emptyTextDisplay}>No Folders to display</Text>
</View>
</View>
 }

useEffect(() => {
const onScreenLoad = async () => {
    const useridfordevices = await
        AsyncStorage.getItem("userDatauserid");
    const obj = JSON.parse(useridfordevices);
    const {userid} = obj;
    var userid1 = userid[0];
    await dispatch(authActions.getFolderInfo(userid1))
  };
onScreenLoad();
}, [dispatch]);
return(  
<SafeAreaView style={styles.MainContainer}>
  <View style={styles.container}>
  <FlatList data={student}
    horizontal={false}
    numColumns={2}
    ListEmptyComponent={renderEmptyContainer()} //**Not working!!!**
  keyExtractor={item => item.index}
  renderItem={itemData => (
    <View style={styles.folderview}>
    <TouchableOpacity
      activeOpacity={0.5}
      onPress={()=>props.navigation.navigate('FolderImagePage',{
        foldername: itemData.item.TargetName,
      })}
      >
       <Image
    style={styles.tinyLogo}
    source={require('../../assets/foldericon.png')}
  />
  
  <View style={styles.textView}>
  <Text style={styles.targettext}>{itemData.item.TargetName}</Text></View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
  )}
 /> 
   
 </View>
</SafeAreaView>
)
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
MainContainer :{
flex:1,
},
folderview: {
width:190,
height:200, 
margin: 7,
borderRadius : 7 
},

textView: {
bottom:'9%',
width:'50%', 
textAlignVertical:'center',
padding:10,
color: '#000',
left:'7%'

 },
 targettext:{
 fontSize:15,
 fontWeight:'bold',
 },
 emptyTextDisplay:{
 fontWeight:'bold',
 fontSize:25
 },
 emptyTextDisplayView:{
 alignSelf:'center',
 top:'60%'.              **Trying to search the text if hidden**
 }
 });

  DownloadPage.navigationOptions = navData =>{
 return{
 headerTitle: 'Back',
 headerTitleStyle:{
   color:'white',
   
 },
 headerTitleAlign:"left",
 headerStyle: {
  backgroundColor: '#0437F2',
  
},
headerLeft: () =>
  <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
    <Item
      iconName={'chevron-back-outline'}
      onPress={() => {  
       navData.navigation.navigate('Home');
      }}
    />
  </HeaderButtons>
   }
   }
   export default DownloadPage;
```

If user doesnt have folder assigned,when I run this code I am getting blank screen.Can anyone say where I am going wrong.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to try

1. Rename `renderEmptyContainer` to `RenderEmptyContainer`
   And then replace

`ListEmptyComponent={renderEmptyContainer()}` with a component signature

`ListEmptyComponent={<RenderEmptyContainer />}`

2. Make sure that the `student` list are empty. Try for debugging just to add an empty array `<FlatList data={[]}`
3. Make another screen where you test your RenderEmptyContainer.

Answer (score 0):

It was my bad,I forgot to add return in RenderEmptyContainer function.And now everything good to go.Find the RenderEmptyContainer code below:

```
  const RenderEmptyContainer = () =>{
  return(
  <View style={styles.MainContainer}>
  <View style={styles.emptyTextDisplayView}>
  <Text style={styles.emptyTextDisplay}>No Devices to display</Text>
  </View>
  </View>
  )
  }
```